# Who is the boy at the end of Feng Shen Ji Season 3?

Tags: feng-shen-ji

Some people say he is Shen Yen, but how? They don't look alike at all, and Shen Yen should have been dead by then. So, who is this boy?

[image: Who is this boy?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boy is Wei Shan, Kong Que's son who we have all forgotten about.

[image: Wei Shan]

He is said to be the next Shen Yen for two reasons:

1. He is a firm believer of Shen Yen's ideals. Also, he has a crystal clenched in his fist and a pair of eyes burning for revenge in the last pages.
2. The five white marks above his eyes, likely the source of power for the five different rays of light possessed by [Kong Xuan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kong_Xuan) (whom Wei Shan is modeled after), look oddly like Shen Yen's eyes.

   [image: 7-eyed gods]